# Find k such that a piecewise function is continuous

Tags: calculus

Find k such that $f(x) = x^2$ if $x \leq 2$ and $f(x) = k - x^2$ if $x > 2$.

My first thought was well, since from the left side $f(x) \to 4$ as $x \to 2$ it seems to me the other part should pick up at 4 as well otherwise we would have a 'hole'. Which leads me to think $k = 8$, as $8 - 2^2 = 4$.

Is it correct that although it has a kink in the graph, the function is continuous because it's defined at $x = 2$

Comment: Correct, but don't say that the function is continuous because it is defined at $x=2$. Function is defined at $x=2$ no matter what value $k$ has. What is important is that as $x$ approaches 2 from left and right side value of function must be the same. That is why $k=8$ is correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is correct. The kink in the graph means the function is not differentiable at 2, but has no bearing on whether it is continuous. It's continuous if there are no breaks in the graph, and a kink is not a break. So your function is continuous if $k=8$. Note that it's not enough that the function be defined. It has to also have no break. It's defined at $x=2$ but not continuous if you choose $k=7.$ Only continuous if $k=8.$

Awesome username btw.

Comment: I don't quite understand one thing though; 'the function is not differentiable at 2'. But $\lim x \to 2^- x^2 = 4$ and $\lim x \to 2^+ 8 - x^2 = 4$, so the left and right limit are the same. So why then is the function not differentiable at 2? Or so I need to check it per piece?

Comment: @Apeiron checking that the limits agree is how you confirm continuity. Checking that the derivatives on the two sides agree is how you check that the piecewise function is differentiable. This function has derivative $2x$ on the left, and $-2x$ on the right. For no value of $k$ will those two derivatives agree as $x$ approaches 2.